# How to insert a placeholder into an aggregated df when iterating over blank spreadsheets

Tags: python

I am iterating through Excel spreadsheets that are located in individual files in a main directory.  Most of the spreadsheets look like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], 
                   "B": [4, 5, 6],
                  "C": [7, 8, 9],
                  "D": [10, 11, 12],
                  "E": [13, 14, 15],
                  "F": [16, 17, 18],
                  "G": [19, 20, 21]})
```

However, about 100 of my spreadsheets are present with the same name and number of columns as my populated spreadsheets, however, there is no data present.  They look like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [], 
                   "B": [],
                  "C": [],
                  "D": [],
                  "E": [],
                  "F": [],
                  "G": []})
```

I still want to "pull" that information, and insert a placeholder for those blank rows.  My expected outcome looks like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, NaN],
                   "B": [4, 5, 6, NaN],
                  "C": [7, 8, 9, NaN],
                  "D": [10, 11, 12, NaN],
                  "E": [13, 14, 15, NaN],
                  "F": [16, 17, 18, NaN],
                  "G": [19, 20, 21, NaN]})
```

Currently, my code does not populate the aggregated spreadsheet with my placeholders (NaNs).  I have tried to df.fillna as well as appending NaNs when checking to see if my df was empty, however, I'm still not populating my aggregated df with my NaNs from my empty spreadsheets. 
 Here's what I've written so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows=999
import numpy
from numpy import NaN

root = "my_dir"

agg_df = pd.DataFrame()

blank_rows = pd.Series([NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN], index=['A', 'B', 'C',
                                                'D', 'E', 
                                                'F', 'G'])

for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk(root):
#     print(directory)
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, file)
        print(directory)
        if file == 'Apples.xlsx':
            df_temp = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name = 'Apples')
            df_temp['Filepath'] = filepath
            if df_temp.empty == True:
                df_temp.append(blank_rows, ignore_index = True)         
            agg_df = agg_df.append(df_temp)
```

Comment: Please share to us sample data/files that you are using so that we can try it out ourselves. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question with my expected outcome - I hope this adds clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank_rows that you created is not one row but seven rows.  So I created one row with None values (NaN is not valid). Then to add a blank row to agg_df, I used concat.

```
root = ''
agg_df = pd.DataFrame()
blank_rows = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([None,None,None,None,None,None,None], 
                                    index=['A', 'B', 'C',
                                                'D', 'E', 
                                                'F', 'G'])).transpose()
for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, file)
        df_temp = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name = 'Apples')
        blank_rows['filepath'] = filepath
        if file == 'Apples.xlsx':
            if df_temp.empty == True:
                agg_df = pd.concat([agg_df, blank_rows])
```

Result:

```
     A      B        C      D       E        F      G     filepath
0   None    None    None    None    None    None    None  my_dir\Apples.xlsx
```

Comment: Thank you for this - where would I add the name of the file when df_temp is empty?  I still need to track which files are empty.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can add filepath at blank_rows since it is also a dataframe.